# Split screen racers - Do any have local MP?

Tags: grid-2, forza-horizon-2, need-for-speed-rivals

Does NFS - rivals, GRiD 2 or Forza Horizons 2 have split screen local multiplayer?

Comment: This is one of those questions that, while valid, demonstrate very little effort.  Hence why it's so heavily downvoted.

Comment: Couldn't disagree more. For some, researching on Google about these games before buying them, this is the research answer.

Comment: Frank - Which is amusing, as I asked it, because it kept getting asked then deleted. In fact, as @maw269 has pointed out, this is now *the* question/answer that google points people to generally. Thankfully I don't care about the rep that much, so I'll take the hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only GRiD 2 has local split screen multiplayer